# Ajax time alert using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have an issue here: I am creating a project that involves planning. A user plans a specific program for a particular time and submit into the database, MySQL, using PHP.

I want the system to raise an alert when the time planned has reached or when it is a few minutes to the time.

Something like

```
if ($selectedDate==CURDATE() $$ selectedTime==CURTIME()){
  // some ajax to provide popup
}
```

I will appreciate useful help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a global variable to store your list of events, not sure what type you would want to use. You will fill the variable from an ajax call (so you can do it on every page of your app), and then iterate over the events to prompt the user.

On page load, you will want to grab the events from your database.

```
$(function()
{
     retrieveEvents();
     promptEvents();
});
```

Create a function that can be called to get the events, and store them to a global variable.

```
function retrieveEvents()
{
    // Make ajax call to get all events

    // Wait 1 minute, calls the function again to get new events
    setTimeout( "retrieveEvents()" , 60000 ); //60000 = 1 minute
}
```

You will then want a function to then prompt the events

```
function promptEvents()
{
     // At this point you will iterate the global variable of events
     // You can check if the event is 2 minutes away, or 5 seconds away
     // In those cases, you would then show a modal or alert box.

     // Wait 5 seconds, call this method again
     setTimeout( "promptEvents()" , 5000 ); //5000 = 5 seconds
}
```

Comment: Thanks I got the setTimeout. In the retrieveEvents() function I'm putting in a regular php/mysql script and dont get the promptEvents() function. Actually, I'm a php developer and I love mysql, but I have challenges with ajax. I will appreciate explicit help. Thank you.

Comment: You can view this site for help on creating ajax with php: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run a repeating ajax call (using javascript setTimeout) and on your second page run a query on the database to retrieve their stored "plan time" and test against current time.  If it is nearing (e.g. 2 minutes away or something) then your ajax call will return a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript's `setInterval` function to check whether the time is closer. Example:

```
setInterval(function() {
    // ajax request and alert action goes here
}, 1000);
```

The ajax check in the above example will execute in every 1 second (1000 milliseconds). You can change the interval as you like, say 5000 (5 seconds).